# Remotely execute pg_dump - psql involving files in local host and invoke it from Java

Tags: java, postgresql, ssh

I have 2 servers, which are **application (A)** and Postgres **dabatase (B)** server.

I have to execute some sql insert in A (let's say from **input.sql** which located in '/var/tmp/input.sql') and store pg_dump result in '/var/tmp/backup.sql'

As I'm not allowed to put any files in B (and there is no psql client installed in A), I have to remotely execute **"psql"** and **"pg_dump"** commands from A using ssh, which involving files in local host (A).

> ssh user@B [command]

I'm exchanging key between A and B so that each time I execute above command, I won't be prompted from password.

Let's say the **pg_dump** command is as following :

> ssh **user@B** "pg_dump --schema db_schema dbname --section data --inserts --column -inserts --verbose">'/var/tmp/backup.sql'

In my java code, I made a wrapper for Runtime.exec function as following :

```
public static int execute(String... args) throws Exception {
    String [] cmdAndArgs = concatCmdAndArgs(args);
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdAndArgs); 
    
    ReadStream rs1 = new ReadStream("stdin", p.getInputStream(), LOGGER);
    ReadStream rs2 = new ReadStream("stderr", p.getErrorStream(), LOGGER);
    rs1.start();
    rs2.start();
    
    p.waitFor();
    return p.exitValue(); 
}
```

**concatCmdAndArgs** is simply a method which iterating through runtime arguments and store them inside an array of String.

I'm able to execute above **pg_dump** script from terminal, yet, when I passed the string to my wrapper, it failed and printed error as following

> 2016-09-05 14:44:35.244 [DEBUG] com.task.ExecuteSqlTask "Executing command:  ssh user@B pg_dump --schema db_schema dbname --section data --inserts --column -inserts --verbose">'/var/tmp/backup.sql'"
>
> 2016-09-05 14:44:35.244 [DEBUG] com.task.ExecuteSqlTask "[Ljava.lang.String;@7a6b8215"
>
> 2016-09-05 14:44:35.308 [INFO ] com.task.ExecuteSqlTask "[stderr] bash: /var/tmp/backup.sql: No such file or directory"

By far, I've tried :

- using (and removing) single quotes for my local file
- using append output redirect (>>) instead of (>)
- joining and separating pg_dump, >, and output file to / from a single string when they're being passed as arguments.

yet it seems that above command still try to find my required file in remote (B) server. Same applied for psql command, which passing sql insert statement from my application server (A) using input redirection (<).

Any thoughts?

Comment: try using jsch instead

Comment: As you have Java installed on the app server, you could use a JDBC based SQL client there (or simply install psql)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name no additional software installation is preferred ;). I think there is some problem with my script, I still couldn't make correct script to be interpreted by runtime.exec.